# Chrome extension sends old cookies with a request

Tags: google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I created a fairly simple chrome extension, that let's people submit links to a site. It sends an xhr request to the site, which is supposed to automatically send the cookies stored for that site, with the request. But it sends older cookies instead. I'm logged in with one account in the site, but the links are submitted under another account. I tried reloading the extension, restarting chrome, even restarting my computer, but nothing works.

Here is the code of the request:

```
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.withCredentials = true;
  xhr.crossDomain = true;

  xhr.open('POST', "https://www.example.com/articles/")

  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('utf8', true);
  formData.append('article[link]', request.link);
  formData.append('article[title]', request.title);
  formData.append('commit', "Create+Article");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("X-requested-with", "XMLHttpRequest");
  xhr.send(formData);
```

I get two errors in the extension console, not sure whether they have anything to do with the bug:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
www.example.com/articles/:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()
```

Comment: Try clearing the cookies for that site and sign in again to recreate the cookies.

Comment: @wOxxOm Now articles don't get submitted anymore at all (even though I did login again)